# Scheduling Notifications in Firefox OS

Tags: notifications, schedule, firefox-os

I just started developing apps for Firefox OS.
Currently I'm working on a Reminder application. I successfully done the adding part, but I need to pop a Notification when the specified time is met.

How can I do this ?

**What I tried:**

I looked [Notification documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Displaying_notifications?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Displaying_notifications) but there is no option for scheduling the notification, there is only  [show()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/notification) method is available for notification object.

Also I checked the [Alarm API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Alarm), but I don't know whether I can use this to display the Message and Description like the Notification in the Notification bar.

Answer (score 2):

A solution :

In the bottom of this article on [Firefox OS](http://rootslabs.net/blog/199-firefox-os-dev-tips-2), it explains how to use WebAPI Alarm.

You schedule your alarm. And you define a callback when the alarm fires which permits you to pop your notifications.

It may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var addNotification = document.querySelector("#add-notification");
    if (addNotification) {
        addNotification.onclick = function () {
            if ("Notification" in window) {
                // Firefox OS 1.1 and higher
                if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
                    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                        if(!("permission" in Notification)) {
                            Notification.permission = permission;
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                    new Notification("See this", {
                        body : "This is a notification"
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                // Firefox OS 1.0
                var notify = navigator.mozNotification.createNotification(
                    "See this",
                    "This is a notification"
                );
                notify.show();
            }
        };
```